# Random test errors with Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to find out why I am getting random errors with the following code

```
const Mongo = require('mongodb')

it.only('x', async () => {
    let db
    const url = `mongodb://test.localhost:27017/nako`; 
    db = await Mongo.connect(url)
    await db.dropDatabase()
    db = await Mongo.connect(url)
    let collection = await db.createCollection('accounts')
    await collection.createIndex( { login : 1}, {unique: true })
    await collection.insert({name: 'yo', login: 'one'})
})
```

Although I completely destroy the database and build again, I am getting two random errors:

- Collection already exists
- Duplicate key error collection (on login)

In which part am I not waiting for an instruction to end? or am I using any type of stale value?

Comment: Is this the 2.2 driver? And with which MongoDB version are you connecting to? 3.2? 3.4? It's possible you are running into "artifacts" of prior behavior, since "collection creation" in particular had no need to be "async" in earlier versions of MongoDB. It's really only newer features that actually require something to be done.

Comment: I am using the Node driver 2.2 and latest Mongo 3.4 . Yes, I was suspecting if there is something going on in the background. Initially the cleaning between my tests (tear up) was just a deleteMany({}) on the affected collection. Then random errors started to occur and I expected that the whole dropDatabase() and recreate again would be the brute force way to avoid them. Right now I do wait for the collection to be created. Is there anything else I have to check, wait for before using my database?

Comment: But are you saying the code above is enough to reproduce? Or are you actually seeing errors where the code is doing something else not listed in that code? I'm generally thinking it's a "possibility" that something could be wrong here. But really don't want to spend hours on it if the code here cannot possibly reproduce such errors, and the actual cause is something else. So in the interests of time management, it would be helpful if you could include some detail that confirmed this small listing produced such errors.

Comment: The code above is enough to reproduce the error. I even made sure that no other test uses a database with the same name to discard a dangling clean up. The problem is that it is awfully hard to reproduce, it happens to me every other day. I have yet to isolate this test in a whole new project and reduce dependencies to just Babel and MongoDB. Today I just wanted some extra eyes telling me if I am doing something obviously wrong in my tear down/up.

Comment: Basically wrong? Not at all. The "two" connects are somewhat of a worry, but cause enough for investigation in itself. Otherwise as I see it, it is perfectly reasonable to expect that all the "async" methods here are actually "async" and therefore respond to the `await` calls for resolution and are **not** *"doing something behind the scenes"* when they tell you they are complete. That latter part is the part for investigation. You could probably raise as a JIRA as well. But we might try some "brute force" to replicate this first.

Comment: Thanks. Normally I make sure that my component tests just cleanup the collections they use. I tend to think that if a whole database drop in a test is needed, there is a design smell.